# Getting Invalid syntax error in python 3.7

Tags: python

getting invalid syntax error for else statement close bracket, is it because of a indentation error or coding error how do i fix this.

```
font= cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
while(True):
ret,img=cam.read();
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y), (x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    if(conf<50):
     user=getUser(id)
     if(user!=None):
      cv2.putText(img,str(user[1]),(x,y+h),font,2,(0,255,0),2)
    else:
      cv2.putText(img,"Unknown"),(x,y+h),font,2,(0,255,0),2)#<-get invalid syntax for close bracket
cv2.imshow("Face",img);
if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
   break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroy.AllWindows()
```

Comment: in which line are you getting the error. Kindly add the output.

Comment: Please format the code correctly and copy paste the full error message.

Comment: get the error at else:
          cv2.putText(img,"Unknown"),(x,y+h),font,2,(0,255,0),2)#<-get invalid syntax for close bracket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra bracket, remove the extra bracket.

```
cv2.putText(img,"Unknown",(x,y+h),font,2,(0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: if i remove the bracket get this error - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\faceid\detector.py", line 35, in <module>
    cv2.putText(img,"Unknown"),(x,y+h),font,2,(0,255,0),2#<-get invalid syntax for close bracket
TypeError: putText() missing required argument 'org' (pos 3)